# Xcode: difference between pushViewController vs segue for view transition

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What is the difference between using pushViewController to transition to another view than Segue?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PushViewController is used for adding a new view controller to a navigation controller stack. Segue is part of the new iOS 5.0 Storyboard system, where view controller transitions can be created and managed through Interface Builder. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) is a tutorial for storyboarding in iOS 5.0.

Comment: So, if you push a view, and then transition to that view in code. Is that the same as setting up a segue and performing the segue?

Comment: Yes. A segue is just the Interface Builder version of pushing a view. A visual way to program it.